# pug: is there any way to update image in template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm creating different images via `canvas` and I want them to show up in real time in my main.pug template, I mean, when one image shows up, I have to reload the page to see the next one, is it possible to 'stream' images without reloading the page?
Code:

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , Image = Canvas.Image
  , canvas = new Canvas(400, 400)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , pug = require('pug');
setInterval(function(){
ctx.font = '30px Tahoma';
ctx.translate(30,0);
ctx.rotate(.2);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = '#2e2e2e';
ctx.fillText("example!", 10, 10);

var buf = canvas.toBuffer();
console.log(buf)
},100)

//server

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('main.pug', {imageData:''+canvas.toDataURL()})
})
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('connected to port 8080');
})
```

template:

```
doctype
head
  title= camera
  meta(charset='utf-8')
body
  .camera
    img(src= imageData)
```

Thank you in advance

---

EDIT:

I've added

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
app.get('/newimage', function(req, res){
   res.send(canvas.toDataURL());
})
```

and edited my template like this

```
doctype
html
  head
    title= camera
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/static/style.css')
    script(src='/static/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')
    script(src='/static/imageGet.js')
  body
    .camera
      img(src= imageData)
```

Now image is moving for a half of the second end then freezes

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new endpoint in Express like so and send a new generated image stream:

```
app.get('/newimage', function(req, res){
   res.send(canvas.toDataURL());
})
```

and on your front end have a jQuery `$.get()` function to call to that endpoint and set the src of the `img` tag

```
$.get("/newimage", function( data ) {
  $(".camera img").attr("src", data);
})
```